# Как выбрать нужный вариант: неспособен или не способен?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, краткое-прилагательное

Приведены 4 предложения **из Нацкорпуса.**

Как авторы выбирали **слитое или раздельное** написание ***НЕ***? На первый взгляд варианты кажутся похожими.

Если не используются **усилительные** слова (совершенно, ни на что и т.д.), то как выбрать нужную форму **по слуху** (например, при диктовке)?

(1) *Всяк человек слаб, грешен и податлив, ни про кого нельзя сказать: «На это он **не способен**».*

(2) *Ну, дай бог. Я на это **неспособен**. Это не мой удел.*

(3) *Да, так вот, если следователь **не способен** понять всего этого, ему у нас делать нечего, пусть идет в милицию.*

(4) *Да, Терещенко дальше своего носа не видит, мелкий провинциальный адвокат, **неспособен** ухватить главное, главное — это то, о чем предупреждал Лева.*

Спасибо.